# Evaluating orbits of symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

$$G = S_4\quad\text{and}\quad a = (1234)(34)^3$$

The actual question is to find the order of $a$ and to then find [$G:\lt a \gt]$. However the part I am confused about is how my professor evaluated $(1234)(34)^3$.

**His working:**

$$(1234)(34)^3 = (123)^3 = 1$$

I understand the last step. What I don't understand is why the $4$ disappeared.

**Here is my theory:**

$$(1234)(34)^3 = (123)(4)^3$$

because the way $a$ is defined, $4$ ends up just going to $4$ repeatedly. We can simplify by removing orbits of $1$ element ie. we remove $(4)$ to get $(123)^3$ as seen. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply two permutations written in cyclic form?

Comment: I understand the concept but I'm still a bit unsure of how to actually do it.

Comment: Your argument is correct, we don't write $(4)$ because by convention fixed points are omitted from this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)(3\ \ 4)=(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$. That's so because:

- $(3\ \ 4)$ maps $1$ into $1$, and $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ maps $1$ into $2$;
- $(3\ \ 4)$ maps $2$ into $2$, and $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ maps $2$ into $3$;
- $(3\ \ 4)$ maps $3$ into $4$, and $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ maps $4$ into $1$;
- $(3\ \ 4)$ maps $4$ into $3$, and $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ maps $3$ into $4$.